# Java Persistence Populating Map with Id's from two different classes

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, composite-key

I have created a basic EAV-Model using Java Persistence (EAV or similar is required because the the users will from time to time create new attributes dynamically at runtime).

I've recently hit a problem that I couldn't solve properly (only with a workaround which I don't like, workaround below, see DataEntity#buildIndex() )

The problem is the following:
A DataEntity is of a certain DataEntityType, this DataEntityType has many PropertyType's which define the properties (Type, Validators, Length and similar). 
A DataEntity has then many Properties, one for each PropertyType that the DataEntityType of the DataEntity has.

The Problem is as follows: (Also see Class DataEntity below for what I'm describing here in code form with comments)
I would like to map those properties like this:

```
Map<PropertyType, PropertyString> strings;
Map<PropertyType, PropertyInteger> integers;
```

and so on.

I've tried doing this with an @EmbeddedId, but that lead to a column with a String as PK that looked like this "12-16" which was Entity.id and Property.id

I would like to avoid this and use the property tables as they are now:

```
property_string(id, entity_id, property_type_id, value)
property_integer(id, entity_id, property_type_id, value)
```

Notice: the entity_id and property_type_id are already here because a Property has a reference to both when loaded as Object!

An other idea I was thinking about was to write a CriteriaQuery run that with @PostLoad but I wanted to ask for some input first before I do that because that is basically the same thing I'm doing now... Also I'm not even sure yet if it is wise to do a more complex query to populate the Map's performance wise... maybe it's even better to do this in the application instead of the database because the data has to be loaded and transmitted either way...

Thank you for your help.

Code below:

```
@Entity
public class DataEntity
{

    @Getter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected long                               id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_type")
    protected DataEntityType                     type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected List<PropertyInteger>              integers = new ArrayList<PropertyInteger>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected List<PropertyString>               strings  = new ArrayList<PropertyString>();

    // CURRENT SOLUTION; CREATE THOSE AFTER LOADING (SEE method "indexData()" below)
    // WHAT IM TRYING TO DO IS LOAD THESE MAPS DIRECTLY WITHOUT THE MIDDLE STEP
    @Transient
    protected Map<PropertyType, PropertyInteger> mappedIntegers = new HashMap<PropertyType,PropertyInteger>();

    @Transient
    protected Map<PropertyType, PropertyString>  mappedStrings = new HashMap<PropertyType, PropertyString>();

    protected DataEntity(DataEntityType t)
    {
        type = t;
    }

    @Deprecated
    protected DataEntity()
    {
    }

    @PostLoad
    private void indexData()
    {
        indexData(integers, mappedIntegers);
        indexData(strings, mappedStrings);
    }

    private <T extends Property<?>> void indexData(List<T> list, Map<PropertyType, T> map)
    {
        map.clear();
        for (T p : list)
        {
            map.put(p.getType(), p);
        }
    }

    // methods to deal with property creation/modification/etc skipped since they have no influence
    // on the mappings
}

@Entity
public class DataEntityType
{

    @Getter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Getter
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<PropertyType> propertyTypes = new ArrayList<PropertyType>();

    protected DataEntityType()
    {
    }
}

@MappedSuperclass
public class Property<T>
{

    @Getter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long         id;

    @Getter
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private PropertyType type;

    @Getter
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity", nullable = false)
    private DataEntity   entity;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "value", nullable = true)
    private T            value;

    protected Property(DataEntity e, PropertyType t, T v)
    {
        entity = e;
        type = t;
        value = v;
    }

    @Deprecated
    protected Property()
    {
    }
}

@Entity
public class PropertyType
{

    @Getter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long   id;

    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_type")
    private DataEntityType entityType;

    protected PropertyType(DataEntityType t, String c)
    {
        entityType = t;
        code = c;
    }

    @Deprecated
    protected PropertyType()
    {
    }
}

@Entity
public class PropertyString extends Property<String>
{

    public PropertyString(PropertyType t, DataEntity e, String v)
    {
        super(e, t, v);
    }

    @Deprecated
    protected PropertyString()
    {

    }
}

@Entity
public class PropertyInteger extends Property<Integer>
{

    public PropertyInteger(PropertyType t, DataEntity e, Integer v)
    {
        super(e, t, v);
    }

    @Deprecated
    protected PropertyInteger()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: No one got any ideas?